# Declare a variable and use it to redirect an output in one line

Tags: windows, cmd

I'd like to set a variable and use it as a file name to redirect an output, all in command-line and in one line.

I managed to print the content of the variable with
`set foo=bar && call echo %foo%` which prints `bar`

Now, I'd like to write `bar` in a file named `baz` like this 
`set foo=bar && call echo baz > %foo%` (this doesn't work, it writes in a file named `%foo%`

Comment: It only writes in a file named `%%foo%%`

Comment: This should work `set "foo=bar.txt" & cmd /c echo baz^>"%foo%"` provided that `foo` is not defined before. Alternatively if you invoke the cmd session with delayed expansion enabled by `cmd /v` then you won't need to use the extra layer of cmd: `set "foo=bar.txt" & echo baz>"!foo!"`

Comment: @sst I love you. I wish I could upvote you but I don't have enough reputation. Please post it as an answer and I will mark it answer. And many thanks for actually reading the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
set "foo=bar.txt" & cmd /c echo baz^>"%foo%"
```

Provided that `foo` is not defined before.
If there is a chance that `foo` maybe defined, or if you use than line multiple times with different definitions for `foo` which causes `foo` to be defined in subsequent uses, then you may use delayed expansion in the second cmd instance:

```
set "foo=bar.txt" & cmd /v /c echo baz^>"!foo!"
```

If your current cmd session is already started with delayed expansion by `cmd /v` then you won't need to use the extra layer of cmd:

```
set "foo=bar.txt" & echo baz>"!foo!"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with variable expansion inside the file:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set foo=bar && @echo baz > !foo!
endlocal
```

Comment: This write in a file named `!foo!`, and the question is in **command-line**

Comment: did you put the above in a batch file?

Comment: That's not the question. The command is meant to be executed in a restricted environment where only one line and the cmd.exe is available.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

`@echo off
 set /p "file=PathToFile"
 set /p "Write=text"
 echo %Write%>> %file%`

Write is what your writing to the file
set /p just sets the variable to the users input.

Comment: It writes in a file named `%file%`, and the question is **in one-line** and in **command-line**.

Comment: actually %file% is a variable

Comment: echo test >>"path to file" && type "path to file"

Comment: I thought the OP said one line

Comment: I did, and it's still not what I am looking for.

Comment: that is one line

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you are looking to do this?

It's possible to create a variable and use it in a single line, but it requires 'tricking' cmd into expanding the variable by instantiating a second command session.

```
SET "foo=bar.txt"&cmd /c "ECHO.baz>%foo%"
```

This isn't the most useful thing most times, but it does exactly what you've asked.

Results:

```
C:\Admin>SET "foo=bar.txt"&cmd /c "ECHO.%~A>%foo%"

C:\Admin>dir *bar*
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is D4CD-98ED

 Directory of C:\Admin

09/25/2019  09:26 AM                 5 bar.txt
               1 File(s)              5 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   4,869,840,896 bytes free
```

edit had this screen up since yesterday and had to re-load chrome this AM but it dint; update the page so I didn't realize someone else had answered this, it updated after I posted.

My answer is essentially an alternate syntax for the accepted answer, as quotes are optional with cmd /c